# Upgrading from jetty 7 to jetty 9

Tags: java, spring, maven, jetty

I'm running a Jetty 7 web application and would like to upgrade to jetty 9. The project is based on Spring framework and uses Maven for dependency management. Once I upgrade Jetty, it fails to start because of the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:348)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:296)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1262)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1197)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 16 more
```

I have tried to identify dependencies that might cause conflicts with servlet-api, using the maven dependency tree tool but that didn't help much. The error is still there.

Currently running Jetty version 7.2.2.v20101205 and would like to upgrade to 9.1.3.v20140225. NB. This error also occurs when upgrading Jetty to version 7.6.14.v20131031. Basically any other version then the one I am using right now causes this error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Jetty 9 is based on the Servlet container 3.0 version. I guess your maven dependencies references the 2.5 or older version of the API

Prior to 3.0:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

3.0.1 and upper:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the 3.0.1 dependency, but the error remains the same. The weirdest part is that I already get the error if I try upgrading to version 7.6.14.v20131031. So even if I only change the Jetty version from 7.2.x to 7.6.x it already starts throwing errors at me. All 7.x Jetty versions are using the 2.5 servlet-api, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would start checking if there is any servlet-api related libraries inside webapp war.